# What are some most used url's to find admin panel?

Tags: admin, penetration-testing

I usually try to search admin panels in bug bounty. I mean that the list of subdirectories that admins use for their admin panel.

Like this one
`/admin`
`/super`
`/superuser[s]`
`/HackTheSiteHere`

I wanna more like this with default URLS of admins of backend services using. Such as php use /phpmyadmin.

I searched for GitHub repositories so that I could find some major used admin urls but that was waste of time going there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try some google dorks on your target. Just search google hacking database in your browser and open first link (exploid-db.com). You can search "admin" in searchbox to filter out admin page related Google dorks. Like this [image: Like this]
2. Identify what technology is being used by host. For example if they are using WordPress then wp-login, login, admin, etc are common URI. So google common admin panel path for the technology you found on host.
3. Perform dictionary attack(burpsuite, dirbuster, etc) using file that contains lots of admin-panel pages. You will find plenty of list in GitHub.
   [For example this link](https://github.com/mIcHyAmRaNe/okadminfinder3/blob/master/LinkFile/adminpanellinks.txt)